# Eval to limited length string

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have the following code which is pulling content for a news article preview. However, the limit obviously only works on the first preview box. I'm trying to make it so that all of the previews have the limit but can't work a way to do it.

```
<%# ((Container.ItemIndex == 0) ? Eval("Abstract").ToString().Substring(0,150) + "..." : "") %>
```

I've tried

```
<%# (Eval("Abstract").ToString().Substring(0,150) + "..." : "") %>
```

But I get this error `Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected`

Comment: you removed the test part of the `?:` ternary operator, but not the false part. `<%# (Eval("Abstract").ToString().Substring(0,150) + "...") %>` should compile.

Comment: Great thats worked thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Vincent G said, I had removed the test part: `(Container.ItemIndex == 0) ?`  but not the false: `: ""`

```
<%# (Eval("Abstract").ToString().Substring(0,150) + "...") %>
```